# Enable UART communication on Pi4 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, 20.04, raspberrypi, serial-port

I have Ubuntu 20.04 (32 bit) installed on RPI4 (4GB). I have loopback wire installed on Pin 8,10.

I need to use Bluetooth and also basic serial communication over Pin 8,10 to communicate with a Roboclaw motor controller.

Did install RASPI-CONFIG on Ubuntu using script at https://github.com/EmilGus/install_raspi-config but even though it installed successfully it loads with improper boot configuration error. That led me to `/boot/firmware` directory where I found `config.txt`, `cmdline.txt` etc. I removed the `console=...`

```
$ dmesg | grep tty
[    0.001061] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    1.919367] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 29, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.924677] fe215040.serial: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x0 (irq = 31, base_baud = 62500000) is a 16550
```

So doesn't look like I disabled the console.  How do I do that?

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyS[0123]
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Jun 27 12:32 /dev/ttyS0
```

```
$ ls -l /dev/serial
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Apr  1 11:23 /dev/serial1 -> ttyAMA0
```

Second when I run `sudo minicom -b 115200 -o -D /dev/ttyS0` (with loopback in place - verified correctly installed)

I see no characters.  No verification of communication with serial.

Tried to change baud, parity, flow control settings with no effect.

Also have a simple serial test python which also fails to send/receive over serial at `/dev/ttyS0` whether I run with `sudo` or without.

UPDATE
I got an updated install script (same github link above) and now have successfully installed RASPI-CONFIG, however while I can run it the directory structure on the RPi4 w/ Ubuntu 20.04 is different enough that it fails to find the config files it tries to change.

```
$ sudo raspi-config
grep: /boot/cmdline.txt: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /boot/cmdline.txt: No such file or directory
sed: can't read /boot/cmdline.txt: No such file or directory
```

I presume that are other Raspberry Pi 4 owners who intend to use the serial port and there's got to be a way to do what RASPI-CONFIG is trying to do on Ubuntu.

I've found the files in `/boot/firmware`

What should I change manually in them that RASPI-CONFIG would do via script?

Comment: Hi! Are you sure the port is enabled? It's disabled by default. I think you can do these things with the raspi-config command. Have you tried it? Unfortunately I don't have a Raspberry-PI here myself so I can't test. Have a look here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

Comment: Have confirmed have enable_uart=1 in config.txt and and have a working version of RASPI-CONFIG which claims to set the serial port correctly but still no communication over pins 8.10

Comment: @BenignFun did you solved the problem? i stucked with same as yours...

Answer (score 5):

I had a bunch of trouble talking to a roboclaw motor on an rpi4 (model B) under Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit). I was able to resolve it, though I had to disable Bluetooth to get there. Unfortunately, I'm not sure at this point how to get there without disabling Bluetooth. **Reader beware**.

Confirmed this works with 5 roboclaw motor controllers on the same serial bus.

That said, here's how I did it (note that this is cliffsnotes of [this procedure](https://github.com/nasa-jpl/osr-rover-code/blob/foxy-devel/setup/rpi.md#5-setting-up-serial-communication-on-the-rpi)):

1. Disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   ```
2. Setup udev rules

   - put below content in new file `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules`

     ```
     KERNEL=="ttyS0", SYMLINK+="serial0" GROUP="tty" MODE="0660"
     KERNEL=="ttyAMA0", SYMLINK+="serial1" GROUP="tty" MODE="0660"
     ```
   - Reload udev rules: `sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger`
3. Add user to `tty` group: `sudo adduser ubuntu tty`
4. Delete substring `console=serial0,115200` from `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`
5. Add newline `dtoverlay=disable-bt` to `/boot/firmware/config.txt` (I put it right under the `cmdline=cmdline.txt` line)
6. Restart
7. (Optional) Feel free to test with this script: https://github.com/nasa-jpl/osr-rover-code/blob/foxy-devel/scripts/roboclawtest.py

Note that after this set up, you need to use `ttyAMA0` (or alias `serial1`), not `ttyS0`. The first uses the full hardware UART, the second uses a "mini-UART" implementation that seems to not work so well under Ubuntu 20.04 (at least with the roboclaw, in my hardware setup. YMMV.). Some more discussion [here on GitHub](https://github.com/nasa-jpl/osr-rover-code/blob/foxy-devel/setup/serial_config_info.md).

Answer (score 2):

I have a setup using both `Bluetooth/hci0` and the `miniUART/ttyS0` at the same time with `Ubuntu 20.04 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-1034.37-raspi 5.4.101) 64bit` on `Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.1` (4G memory). Here is what I did:

1. Back up the original `config.txt` and `cmdline.txt` files

   ```
   sudo cp -pr /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt-orig
   sudo cp -pr /boot/firmware/config.txt /boot/firmware/config.txt-orig
   ```
2. Edit `/boot/firmware/config.txt` to comment out the `enable_uart=1` like below,

   ```
   #enable_uart=1

   cmdline=cmdline.txt
   ```
3. Remove the console setting `console=serial0,115200` from `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`
4. Disable the Serial Service which used the miniUART

   ```
   sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyS0.service
   ```
5. Add the user which will use the miniUART to `tty` and `dialout` group

   ```
   sudo adduser ${USER} tty
   sudo adduser ${USER} dialout
   ```
6. Finally, reboot Ubuntu 20.04, then both `hci0` and `/dev/ttyS0` can work at the same time for me.

Detailed documentation about the UART can be found at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/uart.md

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use a USB to TTL Adapter to connect the roboclaw to a USB on the pi rather than UART GPIO pins.  This will work out of the box without the need for config changes on the pi other than specifying the USB port in the roboclaw driver code.  In my experience it is best to use a SiLabs CP2012 based USB to TTL adaptor (as for example sold by adafruit or available on amazon ) as that chipset is widely supported on linux and other OS'es and certainly on Ubuntu does not need custom drivers.

Answer (score 0):

On my system (**Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS** (GNU/Linux 5.15.0-1044-raspi aarch64)) , I followed @[user1502422](https://askubuntu.com/users/1257164/user1502422) steps to enable UART and Bluetooth:

> Back up the original config.txt and cmdline.txt files
>
> sudo cp -pr /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt-orig
> sudo cp -pr /boot/firmware/config.txt /boot/firmware/config.txt-orig
> Edit /boot/firmware/config.txt to comment out the enable_uart=1 like below,
>
> #enable_uart=1
>
> cmdline=cmdline.txt
> Remove the console setting console=serial0,115200 from /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt
>
> Disable the Serial Service which used the miniUART
>
> sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyS0.service
> sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyS0.service
> sudo systemctl mask serial-getty@ttyS0.service
> Add the user which will use the miniUART to tty and dialout group
>
> sudo adduser ${USER} tty
> sudo adduser ${USER} dialout
> Finally, reboot Ubuntu 20.04, then both hci0 and /dev/ttyS0 can work at the same time for me.

However, in my `/boot/firmware/config.txt` I added `dtoverlay=miniuart-bt` and did not comment out `enable_uart=1`, see [here](https://pinout.xyz/pinout/pin8_gpio14/):

```
dtoverlay=miniuart-bt
enable_uart=1
```

---

Note: I would have added this as a comment but i can't.

Answer (score -1):

exactly the same problem I also have.
A workaround for the wrong path of the raspi-config script may be a softlink like

```
ln -s /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt /boot/cmdline.txt
```

But this doesn't solve the origin problem. I'm sorry.